# Cannot access to web server via local IP address on UBUNTU 12.10

Tags: apache, networking, ubuntu, webserver, ip

Recently I've install Ubuntu 12.10 on my dev machine. also I've installed apache 2.2 &
Php 5.3.8 and Php 5.2.17 and MySQL. Everything works fine and I can browses my sites and projects via 127.0.0.1 & Localhost keyword and  Hostname But I cannot access my sites or Apache web server via Local ip address (192.168.1.5).
I run this model on Laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 and can access via 192.168.1.x.

Do you have any idea about this issue please let me to know your XP in this case ?

thanks a million about your patient...
Farzam.

Comment: Look for a `Listen` directive. It should be something like `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps your Apache is bounded to localhost only. Look in your Apache configuration file
(httpd.conf) for

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

and replace it with:

```
Listen 80
```

or

```
Listen *:80
```

Also check the Firewall settings, look for a the line below in the same file:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

and try changing it to:

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: For a few releases now, the file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file has been empty, and only present for legacy reasons. Now in 12.10, yes, it seems to be gone. Configurations are done in the subdirectories, sites-available, mods-available.

Comment: I check the httpd.conf and modified it to Listen *:80, but it dose not  work for me by IP. also I couldn't find the filewall on ubuntu 12.10 whatever trying to find ...

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the listen line as shown below:

`Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.5
```

Comment: Could you explain the solution?

Comment: ufw (Uncomplicated Firewall) `sudo dpkg --get-selection | grep ufw` will tell you if you have it installed or not.  

If it's installed, this article is a good read for you: 
http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ufw-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

I add Directory tag:

```
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall did not have an exception for port 80.
Somehow IIS worked fine, but would not allow Apache port 80.  Even disabling the Windows Firewall Service did not allow it.

Search Windows for "Firewall" and Create a new rule. Choose Port, enter 80, Call it: HTTP or whatever, Save. Restart Apache service.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i work on nestjs and 
previously i run my project on `app.listen(3001)` like this 
first i change to this `app.listen(3001,'192.168.xx.xx')`

now i want to access my project on the another computer using ip on the network (LAN) 
so it is now allow us to access any particular port after ip address 
means if i access `192.198.xx.xx`  then i can access the address.

but if i append port like this `192.198.xx.xx:3001` then it not let me allow to access ip address so in this case i resolve my problem by run following cmd

1. `sudo service ufw stop`
2. `sudo iptables -nvL`
3. `sudo iptables -nvL|less`
4. `sudo iptables -F`

Answer (score -1):

"Windows Firewall did not have an exception for port 80. Somehow IIS worked fine, but would not allow Apache port 80. Even disabling the Windows Firewall Service did not allow it.

Search Windows for "Firewall" and Create a new rule. Choose Port, enter 80, Call it: HTTP or whatever, Save. Restart Apache service." - This worked for me. After I enabled the ports 8080 on the firewall on Win Server 2012 (I use port 8080).

Comment: This question is not about Windows.