# Issue with connecting Android phone to mac computer on the same wifi network

Tags: java, android, macos, networking, hosting

I'm running a server on my macbook at port 5000. I have an Android application on my phone (on the same wifi network as my laptop) that needs to talk to the server on my laptop.

On my laptop, when I type the following into my web browser I get the proper test page I created:

`http://localhost:5000/test`

Now, to get my computer's IP on my current wifi network I used the IP shown in the Network Preferences (on my computer it is 192.168.1.128). I also used the `ifconfig` command to verify this is the correct IP address.

Now, when I visit the following on my computer, I get a generic "Cannot load this web page" error.

`http://192.168.1.128:5000/test`

When I make a request to that address in my Android application (again, the phone is on the same wifi network), I get:

`failed to connect to /192.168.1.128 (port 5000) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

Which is weird, as my server is still running - I run that localhost url from above to verify this.

If it makes any difference, I'm using the StringRequest from `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+` and am only expecting "Hello, world" back. I don't at any step in the process deal with JSON, encoding or decoding, but it's just text so it should come through and print out on my Android phone.

If it matters, here's the Android code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://192.168.1.128:5000/test";
System.out.println("Requesting...");
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // TODO
                System.out.println("++++++++++" + "onResponse()");
                System.out.println("++++++++++" + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO
                System.out.println("++++++++++" + "onError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Check your server apache configl; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425436/cannot-access-to-web-server-via-local-ip-address-on-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: have you checked your firewall?

Comment: @rakeshkashyap my firewall is turned off.

Comment: @johnelemans I have no idea what that is. I'm running my server off of PyCharm. I just press "run" and it runs. I've tried deploying it to a server but it never works outside of pycharm.

Comment: You have to find out how your apache server is configured. It's the app on your machine that responds to http requests. If it is not configured to accept IP addresses outside of the machine you are on, then you will get that errror. It has nothing to do with your app or phyCharm.

Comment: I've gone to my configuration file and it already had the line ```listen 80```, and as I already said my firewall was already disabled. So that's not the issue.

Comment: If it helps, here is my httpd.conf file: https://gist.github.com/MatthewPageCS/3eee9ac18dc8311302b37946f5eb338a