# How to access a site hosted on apache django over the internet

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a site that is setup on an apache server using django on a linux VM. Here is the conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/sharan/myproject

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1/app_match/static
    <Directory /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1/app_match/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1/proj_VivRx1>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1/proj_VivRx1>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sharan/myproject/myprojectenv>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1 python-home=/home/sharan/myproject/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sharan/myproject/proj_VivRx1/proj_VivRx1/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I can go to the server ip address in the local machine browser and the site works perfectly.
How can I access the site from another machine over the internet for testing?
I tried using the ip address but the "site can't be reached"

Different from suggested duplicate as my question is for accessing over the internet, not from local IP and also, I have already tried the answers suggested therein

Comment: Did you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in Django settings ?

Comment: Yes, I have added  '*' to allowed hosts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access to web server via local IP address on UBUNTU 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425436/cannot-access-to-web-server-via-local-ip-address-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: That question is for accessing through local IP. I am trying to access the site over the internet. Also, I have tried the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

| I tried using the ip address but the "site can't be reached"

This makes me think that you have a problem at a different layer- apache will return 404's if no rules apply for you request URL, 5XX's if there is a problem with your web application (like it if crashes or cannot be accessed).

Site can't be reached suggests that there is a firewall issue or your IP address being referenced is internal when you want to reference the external address.

Comment: Thank you. How can I confirm if its firewall issue? I have tried after disabling firewall. And if its a referencing problem, how can I find out if it is an internal/external address

Comment: You can determine that the machine is reachable via `ping <ip_address>` or `ssh <ip_address>` assuming the firewall is completely off, and that port 80 is open on the server using `netstat -tunlp | grep 80`.

Comment: ping from remote machine to the ip address was timed out.